# Split Signal from Gateway NV59C

Tags: external-display

Using Gateway NV59C, Windows 7, VGA and HDMI outputs. Can I push signal to 2 extended displays (TV's) while the built in laptop display is "sleep." Currently using VGA signal because HDMI is not recognized by secondary monitor. Laptop recognizes the HDMI connection but not pushing signal.